# naturgemäß in der Bedeutung von "natürlich"

Tags: word-choice

Gibt es Unterschiede, was Stil, Angemessenheit und Bedeutung angeht, zwischen "naturgemäß" und "natürlich"?
Zum Beispiel:

> Zu diesem Thema gibt es natürlich/naturgemäß unterschiedliche Einstellungen.

Sind die beiden Varianten hier gleich?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Für mich haben die beiden Sätze eine deutlich unterschiedliche Bedeutung.

> Zu diesem Thema gibt es natürlich unterschiedliche Einstellungen.

Hier verstehe ich "natürlich" synomym zu "selbstverständlich".

> Zu diesem Thema gibt es naturgemäß unterschiedliche Einstellungen.

Hier verstehe ich (ohne weiteren Kontext) "naturgemäß" im Sinne von "entsprechend der Natur/Art des Themas".

Comment: Ich würde widersprechen, jedenfalls für Alltagssprachgebrauch. Die Unterscheidung zwischen natürilch und naturgemäß, die du hier machst, ist sehr feinsinnig.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann ich stimme zu das die Unterscheidung zwar zumindest feinsinnig, ob sehr oder nicht sehr sei dahingestellt, aber nichts das ein durchschnittlicher Muttersprachler nicht intuitive in der Formulierung beachten würde ist. Ob im Alltag die Unterscheidung vom Zuhörer auch wahrgenommen oder auch nur verarbeitet wird sei dahingestellt und ist dann eine sache des feingefühls. Es sollte für die meisten Alltagsgespräche keinen Unterschied machen. Das durchschnittliche gesunde Sprachgefühl sollte dazu schon in der Lage sein. Eine feinsinnige Unterscheidung, doch nicht Verkopft.